# Include C++ standard library

Tags: c++

Is it possible to include the C++ standard library in a single statement, or must you do it header by header?

Comment: There's no `#include <all.h>`.

Comment: It is better you include them on-need-basis, so that compilation and linking would take less time.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no shortcut to include all of the standard headers. You must generally include each one that you require separately.

It's possible to create a single header file that includes all standard library headers—something like `all.h`. However, you should consider whether doing that is a smart move, as it will extend compilation times significantly.

Also, make sure you understand the C++ compilation model before you make such decisions. If you don't already know, find out what's a translation unit, an object file, what the linker does, what's the difference between including a library header and linking a library.

Comment: Alright thanks, that's exactly what I needed.  I don't intend on doing it on a daily basis, I was in a programming competition the other day and both my partner and I knew what to do, but didn't know the library to get what we needed, and we didn't have a reference of them.

Comment: I suppose the best thing to do in such situations is to try and have access to a library reference - not just for the purpose of finding out the header name. The competition rules were horribly stringent if they did not allow that. If you absolutely cannot have a reference, you can try to find the directory where the standard library header files are and listing the directory - it should be pretty obvious in most cases, as many of these are just called after the main class (e.g. container).

Comment: For most of the remaining headers, you should have a pretty good idea what is in e.g. `<functional>` if you've used it often enough, and if you haven't, you'll probably not cope without a reference anyway. As a last resort, you can of course look at and/or use grep or any text search tool on the directory with the standard library headers.

Answer (score 2):

Under Visual Studio you could put all such header files inside your precompiled header file. Since this file is included by all your files all stl hearders would be available everywhere. If all the includes in precompiled header file are from external libraries, then precompilation should speed up compilation times.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no shortcut to include all the standard headers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can include all the headers in your own `all.h`, then `#include<all.h>`,but it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

GCC has a header called `<bits/stdc++.h>`, but this should never be relied on in a typical context.

As noted by the OP, this is the kind of thing you might only want to use in a competitive programming contest, where only running time matters.